# Ag-grid angular 2 - server side pagination

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-ng2

I using ag-grid with angular 2/4 and i set it to infinite mode to use this as pagination mode and i want to disable cache and disable the loading data when scroll.
Nothing in docs